# Gracefully terminate a request based service on server

Tags: web-services, webserver

In our web application, for each http-request there is a lot of computation that happens on back end. Output can vary from 10 sec - 1 Hour. In the mean time when it is computed, "Waiting.." is shown on the website for the respective user.

But it so happens, that a user might cut down the service in between. So what all can be done on the back end so that the computation can be stopped in between to save resources? What different tactics can be applied here?

And if better (instead of killing the thread directly), then a graceful termination policy should make wonders.

Comment: It would help folks if you stated what technologies were being used.  Like what programming languages, OS, webserver (apache,iis 6, iis 7)...

Comment: @jsobo It is pure Java. Spring jdbc and portlets. Though if it can be shown for a simple servlet, I can replicate the same accordingly.

Comment: Do you get notified of a closed connection? If so where?

Comment: @Steve the user might refresh or start teh same service again. So behind we will know that the same computation has started and stop the previous computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this fits your scenario but here is how I have tackled this issue in the past. We were generating pdf reports for a web-app. Most reports could be generated in under 5 seconds but some would take up to an hour.

When the User clicks on generate button we redirect them to a "Generating..." dialog screen which has a sort of progress bar and a Cancel button. This also launches the generate process on the server in a separate thread (we have a worker pool). The browser then polls the server regularly via ajax to check on the progress (either update the progress bar or redirect to the display page when finished).

The synchronization at the server between the generating process and the ajax process was done via a process synchronization object. The sync-obj was a very simple class instance which could be retrieved quickly from any thread at any time via some unique string.

Both processes could update this shared sync-obj. As the report generated the repgen thread would update the sync-obj which the ajax thread would inform the browser. If the User clicked the Cancel button then the ajax thread would set the "cancel" flag in the sync-ob and the repgen thread would pick that up and break out of the generate loop.

Clearly the responsiveness of the whole process depends a lot on how frequently the repgen thread checks the sync-obj and that often comes down to how the individual report was coded.

Finally, to answer your question, if the User gets bored and goes "back" and clicks the generate button again we do not cancel the first report and start a second but rather realise that it is the same report (and the same sync-obj id) and so just let the report continue. However if that does not suit your scenario then starting a generate process could cancel the first in the same manner that the User could via the Cancel button.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. This is what I have done- On request, I start the computation. When I receive another request from the same session -It means user no longer needs previous computation (same requests are cancelled on front end). So the thread will check the previous computation result, if not completed yet; It will interrupt it and request for a shutdown. The first computation will then end gracefully .